# SQL Problems with returning values based on their existence in other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Location   ItemID   AlternativeID
20         1234       9999
22         1234       9999
20         9999
22         9999
20         2345       3456
22         2345
20         3456
```

I am looking for a query that would return any items, where if `ItemID` is both on Location `20`and `22`and the `AlternativeID`on location `20` does not exist in location `22`then `ItemID` is returned.

Like the above one would return `2345` because its exist in both locations, but `AlternativeID` does not exist on Location `22`

Feels like I've tried a lot of overly complicated things, but am missing something obvious.

EDIT:

I think I specified my issue wrong, so here's some more information, to hopefully help it.
AlternativeID is either blank, or have a number, it is never `NULL`

The result I expect, using the example table above is:

```
Location   ItemID   AlternativeID
20          2345       3456
```

Since that is the only entry that has an article that exist in location 20 and 22, with an alternativeID on location 20 that does not exist on location 22.

This is the closest I've gotten by now:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Table] t1
  WHERE t1.Location = 20 
  AND t1.AlternativeID <> '' 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Table] t2 WHERE t2.ItemID 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Table] t2 WHERE t2.ItemID = t1.AlternativeID 
  AND t2.Location = 22)
```

Comment: Also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the suggestions seemed to do what i wanted, might be me defining the question wrong.
I got it working like this, and figured i'd post the answer here anyways.

```
SELECT t.[LocationID]
      ,t.[ItemID]
      ,t.[AlternativeID]
      ,tt.[LocationID]
      ,tt.[ItemID]
      ,tt.[AlternativeID]
  FROM [MyTable] t
  RIGHT JOIN [MyTable] tt ON t.[ItemID] = tt.[ItemID] AND tt.[LocationID] = 22
  WHERE t.[AlternativeID] <> 0 
AND t.[LocationID] = 20 
AND t.[AlternativeID] NOT IN (SELECT [ItemID] FROM [MyTable] WHERE [LocationID] = 22)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation. I think the logic you want is:

```
select itemid
from mytable
where location in (20, 22)
group by itemid
having count(*) = 2 and max(case when location = 22 then alternativeid end) is null
```

THis gives you items that exists at both locations, and whose `alternativeid` at location `22` is `null`. Maybe you want to also specify that the `alternativeid` at location 20 should not be `null`?

```
having 
    count(*) = 2 
    and max(case when location = 22 then alternativeid end) is null
    and max(alternativeid) is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

select query with where clause should help:

```
SELECT itemid FROM test 
WHERE alternativeid is NOT NULL 
      AND itemid =(SELECT itemid FROM test WHERE alternativeid is NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with a `where exists` clause.

**Sample data**

```
declare @data table
(
    Location int,
    ItemID int,
    AlternativeID int
);

insert into @data (Location, ItemID, AlternativeID) values
(20, 1234, null),
(22, 1234, null),
(20, 2345, 3456),
(22, 2345, null),
(20, 3456, null);
```

**Solution**

```
select d.ItemID
from @data d
where d.Location = 20                                           -- items on location 20...
  and d.AlternativeID is not null                               -- ... with an alternative
  and exists (  select top 1 'x'
                from @data d2
                where d2.ItemID = d.ItemID                      -- ... that have a related row
                  and d2.Location = 22                          -- ... on location 22
                  and (d2.AlternativeID is null                 -- ... without alternative
                   or  d2.AlternativeID <> d.AlternativeID) );  -- ... or a different alternative
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NOT EXISTS()` as

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable T
WHERE Location IN(20, 22) 
      AND AlternativeID IS NOT NULL
      AND NOT EXISTS(
                      SELECT 1 
                      FROM YourTable TT 
                      WHERE T.Location <> TT.Location 
                            AND T.AlternativeID = TT.AlternativeID
                    );
```